# Firestore: is it possible with a rule to allow access to a collection depending on specific fields from another collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a question about firestore rules :
Is it possible to allow access to a collection depending on specific fields from another collection ?

In my case, I have a `projects` collection where some ***related manager*** are referred with their ***uid*** inside, and I want to allow users like ***clients*** who have access to theses projects to access the info of the related managers from a `userProfile` collection.

Thanks !

My first try was :

```
// ask for user profile of a related manager
// get projects, filtered where client has access, where related manager exist in it
match /userProfile/{userId} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects).documents.filter(proj => proj.data.clientId == request.auth.uid).some(proj => proj.data.relatedManagerId == userId);
}
```

But the command `=>` is not working and I think it's not possible to user `filter` or `some` in this kind of context, but maybe someone here already work on this kind of issue ?..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in security rules to query the documents from a collection, as that would not scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. In your experience, do you think I could use others ways in Firebase to verify the access right of this kind of collection management? Is there a recommendation of data structure to do so maybe? Thank you